# PHP install instructions?

Tags: php, installation

I need to learn php, but i'm struggling with the install process to run the code in a web browser.

usually when I try to run a php code the screen stays white

I tried to follow the php configuration process from some sites but usually I end up getting lost.

So if anyone knows the steps to install and configure php in windows 7 please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple route to go down is to install [WAMP](http://www.wampserver.com/en/) or [XAMPP](https://www.apachefriends.org/index.html). They are both pre set up with PHP, Apache and MySQL.

Incase you're not sure what each one is... PHP is a scripting language, MySQL is a database, and Apache is a web server capable of running PHP scripts and returning the output to a user.